# Android: imageview animation without shadow around it

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I have an animation.Imageview is walking around a little.
But there comes shadow around the image.
how can ı remove it?

```
    TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(1, 1, 1, -100);
    translate.setDuration(1500);
    translate.setRepeatMode(TranslateAnimation.REVERSE);
    translate.setRepeatCount(1);

    translate.setZAdjustment(TranslateAnimation.ZORDER_TOP);

    imageView.startAnimation(translate);
```

And here are some features of my view

```
imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    imageView.bringToFront();
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setMaxWidth(imageMaxWidth);
    imageView.setImageResource(animal.getImageId());
    imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    imageView.setTag(animal);
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: Screenshot? Code? We can't help you without further information.

Comment: I have added some code.Can you help now?

Comment: Thanks, removed my downvote. Anyway, I ran your code and can't reproduce the issue. The animation runs fine and without any shadows (Android 4.0.3). Are you sure that the images you use don't contain any shadows?

Comment: A friend run tmy code on another device and there was no more shadows. So ı decided it is device dependent.